# How to detect number of elements in a section of a given board

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a board divided into various sections. E.g.

[image]

and I want to count number of dots that are present in a section of this board, so that could have a final result of the kind:

```
A=0
B=0
C=1
D=0
E=6
F=0
G=0
H=2
I=4
```

The size and shapes of the various sections could be different, anyway the kind of patterns that board could have, are few and are already known, so It's not explicitly needed to have a system "smart enough to understand itself how to interpret board structure".

One of my co-worker suggested to use OpenCV, but don't know in what way I could use It to achieve this.

Reading the documentation I haven't clear how I have to use Its feature detection capabilities in order to count dots per section in a picture that reproduces the board pattern of interest.

Comment: will the image have section names as well ? like A, B ? i hope it's not. Can you please add an image without the labels ? it will be easy for us to try something?

Comment: An approach is to convert to grayscale, threshold, perform morphological operations, and find contours. From here, we iterate through each contour and filter using contour area. The largest contour will be the letter (A, B, C), then we find contours in this sub-section ROI. This will give us the number of dots in that letter contour

Comment: @venkatakrishnan the image is just to indicate the kind of problem, however sections of the board of images that I have to use have  labels.

Comment: @nathancy thanks for the hint, the contours' shapes and sizes could have various shape or could be also the same and the detection involves photos so the perspective could alter the proportions of the sections in the pictures that will be analyzed. How I should "map" the board pattern?